# Notepad++ : Strange depency between UTF8 characters for modal logic

Tags: utf-8, windows-10, notepad++

With an UTF8 encoding file in Notepad++, copy/paste the following:

```
∃ → ∃ ∃ ∃∃∃
```

Then replace the arrow by a space, you may expect `∃  ∃ ∃ ∃∃∃`,
but you will get 6 unknown chars (white squares).
Paste again the arrow in any place on the line, the 'exists' symbols are recovered!

So, I cannot set the modal logic sentence `◊∃x[Φ(X)]`  in Notepad++.

I cannot explain. Any idea?

(PS: Using Notepad++ 64bits V7.8.7)

Comment: Does not happen in v6.5.5. Does happen in v7.8.7.

Comment: You should file a bug.

Comment: Same behaviour when I hit enter betwwen `∃∃`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, i have logged an issue on github. More [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/8756)
A patch is available if you want to recompile.
As a workaround, some fonts (and variants) available in notepad (i use win10) does not have this defect:

- Cambria
- some **Noto** (like **Noto Naskh Arabic**) , but not all
- some **Segoe** (like **Segoe Ui Symbol**) but not all
- Some **Source Code Pro** (like **Source Code Pro Medium**) but not all
- All **Yu Gothic** ( i use now **Yu Gothic Ui** for my report )

Thanks to all.